# Docker restarts network on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, docker

I have a problem regarding network when using docker on Arch Linux. When I attempt to connect on any website, or refresh that, download bigger file - sometimes I get `Network Change` error in Chrome/Chromium. The problem was occurring more frequently when I used to use NetworkManager. Someone on IRC channel recommended me to replace that manager with wicd or netctl. Netctl does not work for me, and I gave wicd a spin. That reduced the problem I think, but it still occurs.

Interesting logs in `dmesg` are attached below:

`[18730.570434] br-a315f379ce21: port 1(veth873a3e1) entered blocking state
[18730.570435] br-a315f379ce21: port 1(veth873a3e1) entered forwarding state
[18730.889638] br-a315f379ce21: port 1(veth873a3e1) entered disabled state
[18730.889679] veth3661ba6: renamed from eth0
[18730.938157] br-a315f379ce21: port 1(veth873a3e1) entered disabled state
[18730.938475] device veth873a3e1 left promiscuous mode
[18730.938485] br-a315f379ce21: port 1(veth873a3e1) entered disabled state`

Comment: I also get same issue. How you fixed it? Can you please guide? @jackweb

Comment: @ApoorvaShah in my case there was an unused container, which continuously restarted and changed network. I got rid of that.

it was based on `pkristian/adminer`

You could stop step by step each of your containers and then check if the problem persists.

Comment: thanks @jackweb
I am following this docker file:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker and i am getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to solve the issue! The problem was with some faulty docker container and its network which I don't use anymore. Removing them made it works like a charm.